# How to redirect to a page without affecting seo

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I just hosted my first website 8 days ago. I ran a report in WebMatrix. It said that "This page contains unnecessary redirects". It pointed out the error in almost all of my webpages. All these websites contain the same code. Which is this:-

```
if($_GET['cc'] == "y"){
    if(!empty($_GET['c'])){ 
        $_SESSION['std'] = $_GET['c'];$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];header("location: $url");
}
```

Now if I remove `header("location: $url")` the session value won't change until the page reloads or until the user goes to another page and `$_GET['c']` can have 6 different values so the issue repeats many times. I thought of using a 301 redirect but that won't change the session value either. So I know this would affect SEO. So can you guys tell me an alternative way to do this?

Comment: session value won't change WHERE? if you mean it doesn't get committed to disk, then do a `session_write_close(); session_start()` to force that.

Comment: I meant the data depended on the session variable will only change after reloading the page